# How do I filter out empty textboxes when checking their values in JavaScript?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have a web page that can contain a list of items like this:

```
<input type="text" class="stringItems" value="This is my string 1" />
<input type="text" class="stringItems" value="This is my string 2" />
<input type="text" class="stringItems" value="This is my string 3" />
<input type="text" class="stringItems" value="This is my string 4" />
<input type="text" class="stringItems" value="This is my string 5" />
<input type="text" class="stringItems" value="This is my string 6" />
```

Before sending the data off to my server, I put them all in an array like this:

```
            $('.stringItems').map(function(i, e) {
                    return e.value; 
               }).toArray());
```

So this all works great.

But now I need to filter out `<input>` elements that may contain an empty value like this:

```
<input type="text" class="stringItems" value="" />
```

Basically, I don't want these to be part of the array UNTIL they have a value.

Is there a jquery method that I can use to filter out  elements with empty values?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

try this:

```
$('.stringItems').map(function(i, e) {
     if(e.value.trim() != '')
         return e.value; 
}).toArray();
```

See in the demo the console.log inside your console please and you can see your array without empty value

[**DEMO**](http://jsfiddle.net/TL8nC/)

Comment: Should probably trim the value just to be sure.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion I have edited now, it's a good practice in this control to use trim! thanks again @Karl-AndréGagnon

Comment: @Alessandro Minoccheri You don't have to check `!= ''` cause `''` is a false itself. So `e.value.trim()` is enough. http://jsfiddle.net/TL8nC/2/

Comment: @Bright you are right, but it is better, in this case, to use `!==`. @Alessandro, I know, i am anoying, but it is better to use `$.trim(string)` than `string.trim()` for browser support (ie9 doesnt supprot `string.trim()`).

Answer (score 1):

You're probably wanting to use the filter() method: http://api.jquery.com/filter/

e.g.

```
$('.stringItems').filter(function(i, e) {
  return e.value != '';
}).map(function(i, e) {
  return e.value;
});
```

Answer (score 1):

You can do it all with selectors, i.e.:

```
$('.stringItems').not("[value='']").map(function(i, e) {
                    return e.value; 
               }).toArray();
```